# Why get_categories not working in widgets_init?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I'm trying to build some woocommerce widget for filtering products by category but the "get_categories()" function not working when registering the widget using:

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'FGProductsByCategory_register_widget');
```

but it works when registering the widget using:

```
add_action('init', 'FGProductsByCategory_register_widget');
```

but the widget not showing up in the WordPress widgets section.

so when using the "widgets_init" for registering the widget it shows up in the widgets but the "get_categories()" function not working, and when using the "init" the "get_categories()" function works but the widget not showing up any help, please.

Comment: Because `widgets_init` is fired on `init` with a priority of 1, therefore it fires *before* taxonomies are registered. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request Why do you need to call `get_categories()` on `widgets_init`? Can't you just register the widget (maybe show the code you are using for that) and call `get_categories()` in the admin/frontend display parts depending on where it is needed?

Comment: I was calling the `get_categories()` in the widget constructor and it wasn't working so I tried to call it in the widget `form()` function and it works thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok great. Could you post your widget code as the answer?